# Java Comparing two properties by object references

Tags: java, object, upcasting

When overriding an equals property for one of my classes is it possible to implement it as so? The properties in question such as identifier could be String, boolean, Date, Set, or LinkedHashSet

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;

    if (!compareProperty(identifier, other.getIdentifier())) return false;
    //Continue for all properties
}

//Compares any two objects
private boolean compareProperty(Object sourceObject, Object testObject)
{
    if (sourceObject == null)
    {
        if (testObject != null)
            return false;
    }
    else if(!sourceObject.equals(testObject))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Why or why not?

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you properly but over-riding equals???? you cannot over-ride String class equals() method, it is a final class.you cannot modify its behaviour.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, it is suggested for objects that you override the default .equals method for your object to correctly compare instances of your object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed what should be done.

I wouldn't reinvent the wheel, though. Consider using [Objects.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) (in Java 7), or [Objects.equal](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#equal%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) (in Guava) or an [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) (in apache commons-lang).

Comment: The only one of those that saves you the trouble to specify ALL the properties of your custom class is  EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(obj1, obj2). The others only check nulls and use normal Equal method. But Reflection, as always, can fire Security check alarms and is slow performance. I would stick to  the classic approach, as you did